# Specify Some Function to be executed when Google Recaptcha is checked as i am not a robot with javascript

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Actually my problem is that i want to make an ajax call when a user click on google recaptcha and google verified as i'm not a robot.

How can i do this.
I tried to make a async function with

```
setTimeout(foo,0);
```

And by checking

```
$("#g-recaptcha-response").val()
```

But it is not working!

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this?

Comment: yeah @colecmc I did something like this

var chk = setInterval(function() {
      if ($("#g-recaptcha-response").val().length > 0) {
                         //do some stuff
        }
   
          clearInterval(chk);
      }
  }, 1000);

Comment: OK great. Thanks for the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

After many failures i did the following to achieve my target.

```
grecaptcha.render('htmlelementID', {  //call captcha
          'sitekey' : 'your-key' //Your key
        });

        var chk = setInterval(function() { //function execute asynchronously 
        if ($("#g-recaptcha-response").val().length > 0) {
            // Do your stuff ajax call or something
            clearInterval(chk);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Hope it will help you guys. Thanks